# the bottomnavigation bar contain five items and when selecting the second one ,the remaining items need to change, pages also need to change

Tags: flutter, flutter-bottomnavigation, flutter-pageview

the bottomnavigation bar contain five items and when selecting the second one ,the remaining items need to change, pages also need to change

## [enter image description he[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkTTB.jpg)re](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4zgs.jpg)

the initial state i want[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrmoy.jpg)
and navigate these all pages,
when i selecting the second one [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jda1r.jpg)
need this and , navigate these new items,

Comment: if i get you right you want different icons for active nav bar and non active nav bar, the  BottomNavigationBarItem( ), provides you with a property icon and activeIcon, i believe you can leverage on this to get your expected result, kindly let me know if this helps.